# Laravel 5 custom auth attempt

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

In my database i have 2 fields like "userName", "loginName"
but "loginName" by default will always "NULL"

[image: See Database img here.]

I want to let the user to login using "userName" or "loginName" (loginName can be set by user in future / userName generated by the system)

```
if (Auth::attempt(['userName' => $request->userName, 'password' => $request->passHash])) {
      // Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Auth::attempt(['userName' => $request->userName, 'password' => $request->passHash])) {
  // Do something
}else if(Auth::attempt(['loginName' => $request->loginName, 'password' => 
 $request->passHash])){
  //Do something too
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [];

if ($request->userName) {
   $data['userName'] = $request->userName;
} 

if ($request->loginName) {
   $data['loginName'] = $request->loginName;
}

$data['password'] = $request->passHash;

if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: @NicholasDéziel you had some kind of mistake or something else. if so, please show it